# plot VIIRS raster data (.h5) in R

Tags: r, raster, hdf

Im looking into how to handle .h5 (hdf) VIIRS DNB raster data in R. I would like to plot it or export it as a geotiff.

So far I am able to read in the file with

```
hdf<- h5file("mypath/GDNBO-SVDNB_npp_d20171101_t0110370_e0116174_b31151_c20180208224859630066_nobc_ops.h5", mode = "r")
```

But I cannot figure out how to access the "radiance" band, let alone plot it. I have read the "h5" package documentation without any progress..

As another option I have tried to export the h5 file to geotiff with

```
sds <- get_subdatasets("subset_1_d20171101_t0110370.h5")
gdal_translate(sds[17], dst_dataset = "radiance.tif", overwrite=T) #subset 17 is the radiance band i need
```

however the file has lost its geolocation during the transformation, when the geotiff is opened in e.g. QGIS, it doesnt have any location or projection.

Anyone knows how to deal with these type of files in R?

Comment: HDF5 itself does not support geolocation. VIIRS data is in HDF5-EOS format. This format is an extension of HDF5 with several features including geolocation. When you extract `sds` from the HDF5 file, you ignore location information. You have to extract location information separately and supply it to gdal_translate.

Comment: okay, that already helps in understanding whats happening. Im trying to read the documentation for gdal_translate() but I dont understand how I should supply the location information?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/271102/115